# JQuery Error on Calculation: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'"

Tags: jquery, object, methods, typeerror

i am very new to jQuery and need to create a calculation based upon what users place in 2 textboxes.

My form looks like this:

```
<tr>
      <td with='110'>&pound; $ProductCostEach</td>
      <td with='110'>Per tile</td>
      <td width='55'>
            <input type='hidden' name='pid' id='pid' value='$ProductID' />
            <input name='quantity' class='quantity' type='text' size='1' maxlength='4' value='1' style='width:40px;' />
      </td>
      <td width='110'>
            <button type='submit' class='red'><span class='buy'>Add to basket</span></button>
      </td>
</tr><tr>
 <td with='110'>&pound; $ProductCostPerMeter</td>
 <td with='110'>Per Meter $TileSize</td>
 <td width='55'>
            <input type='hidden' name='pid' id='pid' value='$ProductID' />
            <input name='msq' class='msq' type='text' size='1' maxlength='4' value='1' style='width:40px;' />
      </td>
      <td width='110'>
            <button type='submit' class='red'><span class='buy'>Add to basket</span></button>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when a user enters a value in the input box with a class of .msq I want it to make a calculation, so have written a keyup event:

```
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
      var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
      return result;
}

var convMultiplier
convMultiplier =  0.0625

$('.msq').bind('keyup', function(){
      var qty_text_box = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.quantity');

      qty_text_box.value(roundNumber($(this).value * convMultiplier, 2));
});
```

But having an issue just getting the value of the input box. If i add an alert(qty_text_box.value()) after var qty_text_box = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.quantity'); i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'"

But am struggling to work out what the problem is...

Many thanks in advance,

Danian

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like your string of parent() jquery calls is finding the correct element. If you don't have multiple quantity inputs on the same page you should just give it an id and refer to it that way.

If you have multiple quantity inputs on the page, you should group the button being clicked and the input within a parent element, perhaps on the same row, to make things easier, and then find it through something like $(this).parents('.parentEl').find('.quantity')

Alternatively, you might opt to use $(this).closest('.quantity') to get the input, but without seeing more of the html I couldn't tell you if that would work reliably.

EDIT also your second use of .value needs the parens ( .value() )